# Read binary file into struct and also problems with endianness

Tags: c++, struct, endianness

I want to read a binary file `image.dd` into `struct teststruct *test;`. Basically there are two problems:

---

**1. Wrong order because of little / big endian.**

`printf("%02x", test->magic);` just gives me `534b554c` instead of `4c55b453` (maybe this has something to do with the "main problem" in the next part). Its just "one value". As an example, `printf("%c", test->magic);` gives `L` instead of `LUKS`.

---

**2. No output with `test->version`.**

`uint16_t           version;` in `struct teststruct` gives no output. Which means, i call `printf("%x ", test->version);` and there is no result.

---

This is `exampleh.h` which contains `struct`:

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLEH_H
#define _EXAMPLEH_H

#define MAGIC_L     6

struct teststruct {
    char                magic [MAGIC_L];
    uint16_t            version;
};

#endif
```

This is the `main` code:

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "exampleh.h"

struct teststruct *test;

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\image.dd", "rb");     // open file in binary mode

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't read file");
        return 0;
    }
    fread(&test,sizeof(test),1,fp);
    //printf("%x ", test->magic);   //this works, but in the wrong order because of little/big endian
    printf("%x ", test->version);   //no output at all

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

And this here are the first 114 Bytes of `image.dd`:

```
4C 55 4B 53 BA BE 00 01 61 65 73 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 78 74 73 2D 70 6C 61 69 
6E 36 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 73 68 61 32 35 36 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 40
```

Comment: Reading contents of file as pointer value looks strange. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to read the binary file `image.dd` into the struct `teststruct` so i can print specific parts like `magic` and `version` easily without reading byte by byte into a array/buffer and parse everything

Comment: Which language are you really dealing with, C or C++? `using namespace std;`, `#include <iostream>` and `#include <fstream>` are invalid in the standard C.

Comment: just edit it. `c++`.

Comment: `%c` prints one character, so you will never get `LUKS` from this. ... But `printf("%c", test->magic);` invokes *undefined behavior* (data type mismatch), so you might get that (with very few possibility)...

Comment: `printf("%c", test->magic);` just prints 1 character, you probably want something like this: `printf("%c%c%c%c", test->magic[0], test->magic[1], test->magic[2], test->magic[3]);`. Also `fread(test,sizeof(test),1,fp);` will only read the size of a pointer into the pointer, not the space it points to, you need to do `fread(test,sizeof(*test),1,fp);`

Comment: @BrechtSanders Or `printf("%.4s", test->magic);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You must allocate the structure and read data into the structure instead of reading into an pointer directly. If you are going to read only one structure, you won't need to declare pointers for the structure.
- `printf("%x ", test->magic);` invokes *undefined behavior* because pointer (automatically converted from the array) is passed to where `unsigned int` is required.

In this case, the observed behavior is because:

Firstly, `fread(&test,sizeof(test),1,fp);` read the first few bytes from the file as pointer value.

Then, `printf("%02x", test->magic);` printed the first 4-byte integer from the file because `test->magic` is (converted to) the pointer to the array placed at the top of the structure, and the address of the array is same as the address of the structure itself, so the address read from the file is printed. One more lucky is that where to read 4-byte integer and address (pointer) from as function arguments are the same.

Finally, you didn't get any output from `printf("%x ", test->version);` because the address read from the file is unfortunately in region that is not readable and trying to read there caused Segmentation Fault.

Fixed code:

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "exampleh.h"

struct teststruct test; // allocate structure directly instead of pointer

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\image.dd", "rb");     // open file in binary mode

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't read file");
        return 0;
    }
    fread(&test,sizeof(test),1,fp); // now structure is read instead of pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%02x", (unsigned char)test.magic[i]); // print using proper combination of format and data
    }
    printf(" ");
    printf("%x ", test.version); // also use . instead of ->

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats it, thank you so much! But why is the byte order not working?

Comment: @johndoe It seems the byte order is perfectly working and your machine uses little-endian.

Answer (score 0):

`struct teststruct *test;` points to `NULL`, as it is defined in the global namespace. You do not allocate memory for this pointer, so `test->version` is UB.

`fread(&test,sizeof(test),1,fp);` is also wrong, this will read a pointer, not the content of the struct.

An easy fix is to change `test` to be a `struct teststruct` and not a pointer to it.

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "exampleh.h"

struct teststruct test; //not a pointer anymore

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\image.dd", "rb");     // open file in binary mode

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't read file");
        return 0;
    }
    fread(&test,sizeof(test),1,fp);
    //printf("%x ", test.magic);   //this works, but in the wrong order because of little/big endian
    printf("%x ", test.version);   //no output at all

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `test` may not be `NULL` at `test->version` because something is read to `test` via `fread()` before that. I don't think there are enough chance that what is read is a valid pointer, though.